Where did Soren get Super TNT?
If it's a unique item how did he know the F-bomb (which uses the super TNT when crafted) would explode automatically after being crafted? If he crafted the super TNT what's the recipe?

We actually don't know, I wondered the same. The most reasonable explanation is in the answer below, Soren might have created it abusing the command block. Since he knew it was unstable, he must have crafted it before.

The real mystery is how he lived to tell the tale. Unless he just deleted it with the command block.

From the Minecraft Wiki:


Soren mentioned that the super TNT was one of his uncraftable "impossible items".

It is possible he obtained it using the command block.




Additionally, the Super TNT and the Formidi-Bomb (referred to jokingly as the F-Bomb) are two different items. The Super TNT is a very powerful TNT and is probably unstable as-is. The Formidi-Bomb is even more powerful and so unstable that it explodes moments after being crafted.

I know the Fbomb and super TNT are different but the super TNT is needed to make an Fbomb

The super-TNT texture also has the command block cross on it, suggesting further that it's very much a command block item.
